# Comments should replace HTML links with title as is the case in Question

Tags: feature-request

I really like the fact that when I add a URL form tex.SX in the question, this is automatically displayed with just the title of the question. It would be nice to have this also done in comments, as it is a lot more information to have the title there as opposed to the URL which often is truncated and only the leading part is displayed[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Would be great! Here are corresponding feature requests at meta.stackoverflow.com:

- [Feature request: when posting links to same site in comment display question text instead of URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16609/feature-request-when-posting-links-to-same-site-in-comment-display-question-text).
- [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

I suggest go there and upvote the request, perhaps additionally leave a comment there. There's already information why it hasn't been implemented yet. In short: comments are meant to be lightweight and are processed on the fly while a page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about those other question, and made a request there to at least display the right portion of the link (which has some info) as opposed to the left portion.